# How to obtain class name in a static method in PHP?

Tags: php

Actually my problem is more complicated than the title says.

I want to have a base class with a static method, and the method should be able to obtain the class name of the current class.

```
class Base
{
    public static function className()
    {
        return '???';
    }
}

class Foo extends Base
{

}

echo Foo::className();
```

I expect `Foo` to be the output.

---

As some pointed out that in php5.5 it is simple with `static::class`, I should say I have to use PHP5.3 allowing for the framework we are using. :(

Comment: Why not `Foo::class` ? http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.class.class

Comment: @Hereblur@Sumon Mahmud@Ray Radin. Anything good in PHP5.3....

Comment: maybe get_called_class() ? http://php.net/get_called_class

Comment: Why maybe? It should work. So you can also use  `return   get_called_class()` so you will get return `Class name` as output.

Comment: Hi @Hereblur, maybe you can post that as an answer so I can do accept to it. : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For PHP >=5.3 you can use `get_called_class()`.

Example copied from http://php.net/get_called_class

```
<?php

class foo {
    static public function test() {
        return get_called_class();
    }
}

class bar extends foo {
}

print foo::test();
print bar::test();
?>
```

The above example will output:

```
foo
bar
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `static::class` since PHP 5.5, like this:

```
return static::class;
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply Try this following with `static::class` or `get_called_class()` both will return the Class name from which class calling this static method

```
<?php
class Base
{
    public static function className()
    {
        return static::class;
      // or
      //return get_called_class()
    }
}

class Foo extends Base
{

}
class Doo extends Base
{

}
echo Foo::className(); // Output will be Foo
echo Bar::className(); // Output will be Bar
```

Reference : http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php

http://php.net/get_called_class